# Electroplating diamond grit

Tags: electrochemistry, bond, electrolysis, silver, electroplating

I want to do electroplating with diamond grit and make profiling, grinding and cutting disks. (see the attached photos)

I want to know the process to make the machine or the company whom is selling machinery to do it.

UPDATE :
My question is not about how to shape metal like this, I know how to do it.
My question is that, how can I electroplate diamond grit on the surface of these profiling wheels?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: One **cannot** electroplate with diamonds, other methods have to be used to cover things with them.

Comment: Well, you can electroplate from a bath containing diamond bits, encapsulating some diamond in the film. It is a pretty standard industrial process.

Comment: @JonCuster Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @JonCuster Please give me some documentations if you have. Any source or tutorial about it?

Comment: Googling 'electroplating diamond grit' produces a wealth of sites. Since it is an industrial process, likely each firm has their own 'magic recipe', but you could start at, say, https://www.dpcanada.com/en/articles/plating-brazing

Comment: @JonCuster I have done the googling a lot and have read your shared link many times, None of the sources on internet has referred to details of the process, Until now, I know how to plate nickle on the surface of work piece but the problem is plating diamond grit with nickle together on the surface of work piece, one guy has told I should suspend diamond grit in electroplating bath but had not give more detail about how to do that!

Comment: Yes, likely a problem for such processes.  Each company has their trade secrets.

Comment: Tou can make the form blanks and send them to norton abrasives and they can diamond electrolyte them for you. It doesnt cost as much as you would think, and when they are worn out just send them back. If you go on thier website they have all of the info in printable form in the diamond abrasives catalog. It covers dimensions for blanks to be undersized before coating. I am a toolmaker we use them for fine radii on punches and other tooling. Hope this helps. James

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these links would help:
US3046204A - Method for making diamond tools - Google Patents
https://patents.google.com › patent

The Basics: Electroplating & Vacuum Brazing - Diamond ...
https://www.dpcanada.com › articles › pl...

US4079552A - Diamond bonding process - Google Patents
https://www.google.com › patents

https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/matertrans/43/10/43_10_2604/_article/-char/ja/

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263436808001649

https://patents.google.com/patent/US6286498B1/en